# Jump into #include file in XCode 3 C++ project

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

If my code does either:

`#include "file.h"`
`#include <file.h>`

How can I jump into those files? I'm aware of "find quickly" and the "popup of included files" dropdown '#' menu, but these both only work for local includes for me.

I'm sure I found a way once but then forgot it when I stopped working on Mac for a while and now I cannot find it again :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried command clicking on the the import?